# Running gulp tasks in sequence throws `Unhandled stream error in pipe`

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task as following :

```
gulp.task('build-files, function(cb) {
    runSequence('run-build-cmd',
        'delete-dest', 'copy-files',
        cb);
});
```

This task is running whenever something changed in a source folder as following :

```
gulp.watch(pathToSrcFolder, ['build-files']);
```

So this task runs 3 other gulp tasks in the specified order, the first one it runs a build command, the second one will delete a folder as following :

```
gulp.task('delete-dest', (cb) => {
    del([pathToDestFolder], {force: true});
    cb();
});
```

and the third one will copy files from a source into two destinations :

```
gulp.task('copy-files', () => {
    return gulp.src(pathToSrcFolder)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToDestFolder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(anotherPath));
});
```

Please notice that the pathToDestFolder is the same folder in both `delete-source` and `copy-files` commands.

The problem I had running this sequence, is this error:

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'pathToDestFolder\path\to\some\file\file.ext'
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error.

And when I run the `gulp delete-dest` in cmd prompt (which will clear the pathToDestFolder) and then `gulp copy-files` (which will copy the source folder into two folders pathToDestFolder and anotherPath) it works as expected .

So I guess `runSequence` didn't work as expected ? if so, how can I solve this ?

## Edit:

I tried to use `rimraf` instead of `del`, and all seems to work just fine, I know that `rimraf` is depricated, and it's better to use `del` instead, but why `del` in this case results in an exception ?

## Edit 2:

Instead of using `rimraf` as a solution, I tried this solution:

```
gulp.task('delete-dest', (cb) => {
    del([pathToDestFolder], {force: true})
    .then(paths => {cb();});
});
```

And it worked like magic.

Why this worked instead ? I don't know !

If someone can clarify things I would be greatful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del#delpatterns-options), you'll find that `del` returns a promise. It's an async method.

In your code, you call the `cb()` right after calling `del(...)`, **but before `del` actually finishes deleting the directory.**

That's why you have to execute the callback after chaining with `then`:

```
gulp.task('delete-dest', (cb) => {
    del([pathToDestFolder], {force: true})
    .then(paths => {cb();});
});
```

And then your operations will run in the correct order.

The error you were getting before is the result of things being run in a weird order, leading to weird behavior. Gulp is trying to copy to a directory while the file system is deleting it, and that conflict leads to a file system error.

---

As an experiment, you can try running the synchronous version of `del` like so:

```
gulp.task('delete-dest', (cb) => {
    del.sync([pathToDestFolder], {force: true});
    cb();
});
```

See if that works (though you should prefer the async version).

---

As a side note, unless this is a feature of Gulp 4 though probably not, rather than calling a callback in your task, you can just return a promise like so:

```
gulp.task('delete-dest', () => {
    return del([pathToDestFolder], {force: true});
});
```

That will tell Gulp that your task is finished, and it can move on to the next.